# Is there a Windows alternative for UNIX crash core-files

Tags: windows, unix, crash, dump

I am facing a crash on a Windows system at customer premises. I had such situations regularly in the past when I was working for customers with UNIX computers. In that case, I only needed to investigate the core files and I knew about where the crash has happened.

Does such a system exist for Windows environment, and in case yes, how does it work and on which Windows systems is it supported? (I've been looking on the internet but the only dumps (cores) I've found where the ones where the whole Windows system crashes, not just a program)

Thanks

Comment: This question may be better suited to [so]

Comment: Thanks, I copied the question to the StackOverflow forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can *cause* a dump file to be created for a program by killing it from the taskmanager and choosing create dump file

This will create normally in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp

However I'm unsure how you'd go about automatically creating dumps when a program dies unexpectedly (which is what I think you require).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that feature in task manager, but as you mention indeed I'm looking for the dump of an unexpected crash.